# MongoDB GROUP BY and COUNT unknown keys

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I am trying to GROUP BY and COUNT each key in each Mongo document but the keys may differ from document to document. I know how to group and count by explicitly calling each key like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([{"$group" : {_id:"$vcenter", count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

but how do I iterate through each key of each document without having to call out keys. I'm thinking a mapreduce function?

Here's a sample document:
    "key1" : "vmx",
    "key2" : "type",
    "key3" : "cpu-idle",

and I'm looking for how many records per key like:
    "Key1" : 1564
    "Key2" : 1565
    "Key3" : 458

Comment: Would be really great if you could show us some sample test documents and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I can only think at mapreduce, since [in the aggregation $group the _id is mandatory](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). So I'd write

**map**

```
function map(){for(var prop in this){emit(prop,1)}}
```

**reduce**

```
function reduce(key,values){return values.length;}
```

**run command**

```
db.inputCollectionName.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out:"outputCollectionName"})
```

You should then find in your output collection something like

```
{ "_id" : "key1", "value" : 1564 } 
{ "_id" : "Key2", "value" : 1565 } 
{ "_id" : "Key3", "value" : 458 }
```

Is that good for you?